# How to export a variable that has value assigned aysnchronoulsy from a module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-structure

consider this,

```
let value = "";
value = DATABASE_CALL();

module.exports = value;
```

When I require the above module in an another module and try to access the variable 'value', it is an empty string. How can I make the module.exports wait until the above DB call is completed and the variable is assigned a value?

Comment: Export a function that calls the database?

Comment: I assume `value = DATABASE_CALL(0;` is a stand-in for asynchronous code. If it were really synchronous like that, you'd just use it as the initializer value on `value`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Could you please elaborate your point?  it will be useful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot make the module "wait". Instead of exporting the value, export a function (an *asynchronous* function) that can be used by a module that imports this module to get the value.

Comment: I agree with you @T.J.Crowder, the DB call is an asynchronous piece of code, though you put `let value = DB_CALL();` then export it, it has value `undefined` in the other module. How can I handle this situation? Thanks in advance

Comment: `module.exports = DATABASE_CALL`

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I understood it, its a good one, I will try it, is there any other solutions for this, any other ways of achieving this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @vanowm, just to confirm, is this the official way of handling the situation ?

Comment: @Pointy - Well, you can now with ESM and top-level `await`. But the OP is using CommonJS...

Comment: @SooryaJ - There are no official ways, and note that what vanowm has shown is completely different to what your original code was trying to do. It's just exporting the function, not the value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, that's clear. However wouldn't the exporting module need to export the Promise? (Well I guess that's what it'd do if `DATABASE_CALL()` was `async` or returned a Promise explicitly.)

Comment: @Pointy - Not with top-level `await`, its purpose is to hold up module resolution until the promise settles (making module resolution fail if the promise rejects, though of course you could handle the rejection instead if you have a reasonable fallback value or similar). The code importing just sees the exported binding and doesn't know that the module waited for a promise before supplying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `value = DATABASE_CALL();` is a stand-in for asynchronous code. (If it were really synchronous as shown there, you'd just use it as the initializer value on `value`.)

You have a few options for exporting a value that's only available asynchronously:

1. Using ESM instead of CommonJS and using top-level `await` to prevent he module from finishing loading until the database operation is complete.

   ```
   export default await DATABASE_CALL();
   ```

   ...where `DATABASE_CALL` returns a promise. (If it doesn't already, you can [wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).)

   Code using it **won't** have to `await` it, but the module won't finish loading until the DB op is complete, and won't load at all if the DB op fails.

   This is really only appropriate if the module cannot be used **at all** without that value.
2. Exporting a promise of the value (whether you switch to ESM or keep using CommonJS):

   ```
   module.exports = DATABASE_CALL();
   ```

   ...where (again) `DATABASE_CALL` returns a promise.

   Code using it would have to `await` the promise (or use explicit `.then`/`.catch`).
3. Using ESM instead of CommonJS and using a flag value to indicate "not ready yet" (`null` and `undefined` are useful for that) and updating the value when the database call is complete:

   ```
   export let value = null;
   // ...later when DATABASE_CALL is complete
   value = /*...the value from the DB...*/;
   ```

   ESM exports are *live bindings*, meaning that if the source module updates the variable, imports in other modules see the updated value.

   **Note:** You can only do this with named exports (`value` in the example), not default exports.

   Of course, that means the code using it has to allow for the possibility it's not loaded yet.
4. Exporting a function that provides the value, and that handles telling the caller the value isn't available yet (implementation left to the reader).

There are probably other choices.

In cases where the module is worthless without the asynchronous information, I usually use #1. If not, I usually use #2.